# Hyperpluralfolgen

Tags: noun, vocabulary, grammatical-number

On page 77 in [Topologische Differentialalgebra by U. Gebhardt et al.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180823182324/http://siebzehn.info/TDAges.pdf) which I found on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199926/parodies-of-abstruse-mathematical-writing/285937#285937), there is this exercise that asks the reader to find sequences of consecutive singular/plural pairs:

> **Aufgabe 4 (Hyperpluralfolgen)**
> Eine Folge von Substantiven (*S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>*) heißt **Hyperpluralfolge der Ordnung** *n* (kurz: *H<sub>n</sub>*-Folge), wenn folgende Bedingungen erfüllt sind:
> a) Die *S<sub>i</sub>* sind paarweise verschieden
> b) Für *i < n* gilt: *S<sub>i+1</sub>* ist der Plural von *S<sub>i</sub>.*
> **Beispiel:** (*Herd, Herde, Herden*) ist eine *H<sub>3</sub>*-Folge.
> Geben Sie drei weitere *H<sub>3</sub>*-Folgen und eine *H<sub>n</sub>*-Folge (*n > 3*) an!

Additionally to Herd, Herde, Herden there is Kohl, Kohle, Kohlen as well as Term, Terme, Termen (note that Terme references a border stone) and Spalt, Spalte, Spalten. Does someone know a hyper plural sequence of order 4 (or higher)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133857/discussion-on-question-by-bixxli-hyperpluralfolgen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bakunin's argument](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69588/15393) makes us look for different forms of plural endings. The first candidate is a stem that forms the plural with  *-s* followed by a plural with *-e*:

If we accept the brand name *Rei* as a German word, then the following fits into that Schema:

**Rei** [in der Tube] → **Reis** [multiple cans of Rei in der Tube, but also the plant, *rice*] → **Reise** [different kinds of rice, but also the journey] → **Reisen**

Same schema:

**Wie** [the question word] → **Wies** [multiple question words *Wie*, but also a town, for instance in Austria or Bavaria] → **Wiese** [the collection of all those towns with the name *Wies*, but also the meadow] → **Wiesen**

In a comment below, Wolfgang Spindeler gave the sequence

**Mu** [see [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(Philosophie))] → **Mus** [multiple words *Mu*, but also a mush like applesauce for instance] → **Muse** [a muse] → **Musen**

[That is Community Wiki answer. Just append solutions by editing.]

Comment: Vielleicht gibt es auch noch andere Lösungen, wenn man fremdsprachige Pluralbildung hinzuzieht. Gute Chancen hat man vielleicht bei Lateinischen Fremdworten. Ich denke an so etwas wi **Jus** → **Jura** als Anfang. Oder etwas nach dem Endungsschema **-us**  → **-is** → **-ise** → **-isen**. Hat man erstmal ein solches Endungsschema, kann man ein Reimwörterbuch daraufhin befragen.

Comment: OK, if we take made up names (trademarks) like "rei" into account we can make up as long sequences as we want. We just have to claim that in i.e.: "xy", "xye", "xyen", "xyene", "xyenes", "xyeneses", etc.,  are trademarks. The task was "eine Folge von Substantiven", though, and "rei" is not a Substantiv - nor is "xy".

Comment: Furthermore i wonder if "Substantiv" doesn't imply a german word. i.e. an english equivalent of a "Substantiv" would be called "noun".

Comment: @bakunin Why would "Rei" not be a German "Substantiv"? It is not a trade mark I invented, but it does exist in German.

Comment: Added Mu as first answer to the list because it might very well be possible that the authors of the source (who are mathematicians and are probably aware of the book “Gödel, Escher, Bach” by Douglas R. Hofstadter as well as the MU-puzzle, see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle)) thought of this themselves and hence came up with that exercise. (Only a hypothesis.)

Comment: @JonathanScholbach *Why would "Rei" not be a German "Substantiv"?* Ausgerechnet weil propere Nomina keinen Plural haben, so wie es auch keinen Plural von *Jonathan Scholbach* geben kann. Morphologisch ist das natürlich denkbar, dann kann ich aber auch plurale von beliebigen Zeichen bilden, ein e, zwei ee, viele eee, ganz viele eeee - argumentum ad infinitum - was etwas einfacher ist als bakunin's Ansatz. Lol, können wir das bitte in vereinfachter Form aufnehmen, ein e, viele e, zu viele e, viel zu viele e? Nicht zu verwechseln mit *Es*.

Comment: @vectory Wie erklärst du dann _Ich habe mir zwei neue Teslas gekauft._?

Comment: Willst du nicht lieber *zwei Automobile der B.M.W.* kaufen anstatt *der Tesla's*? Das ist natürlich ein Lehnparadigma, entsprechend dem Trend zum Leihwagen. Fraglich bleibt, wie die entsprechenden Endungen überhaupt entstanden. Gerade deshalb gilt, dass meinereiner nicht akzeptiert, wenn immer neue Bildungen mit derlei Endung angestellt werden würden. Mehrzahl von *Rei* müsste dementsprechend *Tuben* lauten, rein analytisch: *Rei* (*Tuben* - *Kisten* - *Wagenladung* - *Werk*). Da ich Rei von Uhu nicht unterscheiden kann, ist die Herkunftsangabe wichtig - s. Evidentiality.

Answer (score -1):

Ich glaube nicht, daß es eine Folge mit n > 3 geben kann. Der Grund ist, daß H<sub>3</sub>-Folgen als drittes Element ein Wort mit der Endung -en haben ("Kohl", "Kohle", "Kohlen") und bei Wörtern, die auf -en enden, der Plural gleich dem Singular ist, sofern sie überhaupt einen Plural haben (zB. "das Leben", "der Pfosten"), was bei substantivierten Verben ("das Gehen", etc.), die vermutlich den größten Teil dieser Wortgruppe ausmachen, nicht der Fall ist.

Dieser Umstand aber verletzt die Forderung, daß die Wörter "paarweise verschieden" sein sollen.

Ich frage mich aber, was das mit Topologie oder Funktionenanalysis zu tun hat.

Comment: I think in principle sequences for n = 4 are possible, though I don't have an example. As a probably wrong example, however illustrating the possibility of existence consider the word "Mu". Looking up it's meaning there are some, like a mythical continent or a Chinese measure of area. Assume there is a meaning having plural "Mus" (which I don't know there is) then we can go on like: Mu, Mus, Muse, Musen. (Der oder Das Mus, as in "Apfelmus", Die Muse as in "die Muse hat mich geküsst")

Comment: Please write answers always in the same language as the question. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1050/1487 and https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: The questions title was in german, the text of the question too.

Comment: @WolfgangSpindeler Whether the name of the continent is correct may be debatable and I think the plural form of the area unit is again Mu if am not mistaken. But to me, the title of https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(Philosophie) seems to be a noun with plural „Mus“ and then your solution should work out.